# Flutter textfield layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I got:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
      Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 25.0,
            maxHeight: 100,
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              controller: inputTextController,
              maxLines: null,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 13),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Type a message',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff99999B),
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Tried wrapping the container with row but it overflows. Also tried wrapping the TextField with Row but the TextField disappear. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from the image that you have provided I have created and example for you which might be ok for your use case check the description below that for the UI implementation:

1. So there is a row which has three widgets.
2. In which First widget is a card with Expanded to scale as per the Device size then comes the child with another row which has the following widget :

   1. Icon button for emoji's stuff.
   2. TextField with expanded to scale for device sizes.
   3. And Next one comes the camera widget which is again a       IconButton.
3. There is a Floating action button in the end.
4. Container for right padding, you can use widget of your choice.

check the Git repo, this has a sample code:
https://github.com/sagaracharya24/chat_app_input_widget.git

This is the end output:

[image]

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your TextField Container with `Flexible` before you wrap it with Row, solves the problem mainly.

Here is the entire code:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: 25.0,
              maxHeight: 100,
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            child: Scrollbar(
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                // controller: inputTextController,
                maxLines: null,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mood, color: Colors.black45),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt, color: Colors.black45),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13, vertical: 13),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Type a message',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff99999B),
                    )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.send),
            onPressed: () => {},
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Comment: ah i see, but what about the icon button inside the textfield?

Comment: They are called prefix and suffix icons, inside InputDecoration of textfield.
`prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.insert_emoticon),
suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),`